# TDengine cannot get machine code in k3s environment

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

Prepare to host TDengine on k3s.

With docker, i use such command to generate the machine code in docker container.

```sh
docker run --privileged -it --rm xxxx tasd -k
```

But it failed like this:

```
should generate machine code under root authority!
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've added securityContext in helm chart, and it works.

```yaml
securityContext:
  privileged: true
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
  runAsUser: 0
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
```